# how to save logs in external file using slf4j api in nodejs

Tags: node.js, slf4j

I am trying to write logs in an external file for my nodejs application using slf4j api. But I am not able to find any help/docs for the same. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You may like to use [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) rather than other logging because [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) is still in development and maintain by many contributes. You may create a separate file like `log.js` and use logging configuration. Here is a example of minimal configuration

```
var winston = require('winston');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({ json: false, timestamp: true }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: __dirname + '/debug.log', json: false })
  ],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({ json: false, timestamp: true }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: __dirname + '/exceptions.log', json: false })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});

module.exports = logger;
```

and then use anywhere as like other module `logger = require('./log');` or call in your starting point and make it global `GLOBAL.logger = require('./log');`. Now you may use anywhere without require like

```
logger.info('It is working')
```

I hope this will help you